# Would a short postdoctoral training period hurt in the resume of a PhD?

Tags: resume, job-search, hiring-process, career-switch, employer

Let's say that, after a STEM PhD, someone gets a postdoctoral position in academia. But after a few months of -productive- work, they realize that non-academic jobs would suit them better.

Will non-academic employers consider this as a red flag in a resume?

[Disclaimer 1: It might seem a duplicate of many other questions such as this [Is it bad to switch jobs many times in a short period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52515/is-it-bad-to-switch-jobs-many-times-in-a-short-period) 
But, in this case, it's not a matter of switching multiple jobs, but about having a short postdoctoral training period.]

[Disclaimer 2: inherited from https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93608/whats-the-shortest-acceptable-postdoc-length]

Comment: In many companies, all that matters is your experience and probably your age.

Comment: I think the only risk is that an employer might think that a brief stint at anything means you aren't good at sticking at things (having a PhD seems a good counter) or getting along with others. Neither has much to do with being postdoc, and generally a single short stint wouldn't be seen as too negative - only if there were multiple, so it started looking like a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will non-academic employers consider this as a red flag in a resume?

I do not think so. Worst case is that company will not consider your post-doc experience as a 'real experience' and may not weigh that in during selection process.

However, lot of companies with good research focus (Where I assume you would want to go) may actually value post-doc experience. I knew lot of folks in my team who joined our industry research group after post-doc and did very well for themselves in career progression.